# OpenSSL causing Windows XP to crash when reading

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, openssl, windows-xp

I have a simple C app that downloads some file on an HTTPS enabled web server. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and it works great on all Windows platforms, except Windows XP.

As far as I noticed, SSL/TLS support is completely obsolete on windows XP. I was not even able to reach certain websites with HTTPS on Internet Explorer. However, OpenSSL is still supposed to work, right?

The program seems to be working until BIO_read is invoked. I tried many things, different VS toolsets, etc. I still can't manage to download without a crash.

Here is the base code in the app where the crash occurs:

```
SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
SSL * ssl;

BIO * bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "www.myhostname:443");

if (BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0)
{
    printf("BIO: couln't connect.\n");
}

char  request[500];
strcpy(request, "GET /myfile.zip HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ");
strcat(request, myhostname);
strcat(request, "\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");

int len = BIO_write(bio, request, (int) strlen(request) );
char buffer2[32];
while ((len = BIO_read(bio, buffer2, 32)) > 0) {
    fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(char), len, archive);
    fflush(archive);
}
```

I'm using precompiled OpenSSL binaries from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Comment: There are a lot of gaps in your code. Start with the code at [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: I tried the wiki code, same error, when i invoke BIO_puts or BIO_write, always crashing.

Comment: Still haven't got a clue why this issue only happens on windows XP. Anyone else ?

Comment: I managed to download the file without a crash. Issue was not openssl. I simply cannot write to a file in another location than the current location where the program is executed (very weird issue).

Comment: *"I cannot write to a file in another location than the current location where the program is executed..."* - That is kind of weird. Is this a mobile app in a sandbox or walled garden? In any case, you should add an answer. it is OK to answer your own questions.

Comment: i got the answer. it was actually a big mistake from me. i was actually creating multiple folders when downloading and unzipping my file (zip file), one of the filepaths was causing the program to crash simply because it had spaces in it...